# Adding Standard Widget to Homescreen programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to add existing widgets like calender, Music widgets to HomeScreen in Android programmatically?

Thanks,
Bhavani

Comment: What you want to add to your Homescreen? Describe briefly here.

Comment: Say,I want to add Calender widget to Home Screen from my application

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Only you can create a widget host yourself and let user add existing widgets to that.